# NSAssert1 with handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want use NSAssert1 and handle the assertion with **handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description**. I referred docs where description format must be provided as comma separated formatted strings.

Kindly help me how i can pass arguments so that it will be handled through description parameter with some example code. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)handleFailureInMethod:(SEL)selector
                       object:(id)object
                         file:(NSString *)fileName
                   lineNumber:(NSInteger)line
                  description:(NSString *)format, ...
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, format);
    NSString *formattedString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:format arguments:args];
    va_end(args);

    NSString *location = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%i: %@::%@", [fileName lastPathComponent], (int)line, [object class], NSStringFromSelector(selector)];
    NSLog(@"NSAssert: %@\n%@", location, formattedString);
}
```